# ССылка на неразрешённый элемент qt

Tags: c++, qt

> LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "private: void __cdecl
>   MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(void)"
>   (?on_pushButton_clicked@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ) в функции "private:
>   static void __cdecl MainWindow::qt_static_metacall(class QObject
>   *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@MainWindow@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
>   и LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "private: void
>   __cdecl MainWindow::on_pushButton_released(void)" (?on_pushButton_released@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ) в функции "private:
>   static void __cdecl MainWindow::qt_static_metacall(class QObject
>   *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@MainWindow@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)

такие ошибки выдаёт моя программа в qt. До появления этих ошибок я приклеплял к pushButtton слоты released() и clicked() но потом убрал их. помогите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите декларацию этих слотов (`on_pushButton_clicked`, `on_pushButton_released`, ...) не только из *.cpp файла, но и из заголовочного файла (MainWindow.h).